# How to prove that $\int^a_bf(x)dx=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0}\sum_{x=a}^bf(x)\Delta x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to prove that $$\int^a_bf(x)dx=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0}\sum_{x=a}^bf(x)\Delta x$$
(which $\int^a_bf(x)dx=g(a)-g(b)$ where $\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=f(x))$?

I know this is a very basic thing of integration but it seems that I can't its proof anywhere. Please help me... Thank  you.

---

Maybe I should say it in this way: prove that $\int^a_bf(x)dx$ is the area between the curve y=f(x) and x-axis in the interval [b,a].

Comment: How do you define $\int_a^b f(x)dx$?

Comment: What is $$\sum_{x=a}^b$$ anyway?? Are $\,a,b\,$ integers so that the variable $\,x\,$ can run between them? I think there's a serious mistake/typo in this question.

Comment: That is the definition of the integral in most of the calculus books. Well, except for a few typos.

Comment: Please see my question similar to yours. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123048/the-net-signed-area-between-t-0-y-0-t-x-and-y-ft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want a proof that shows that if

$$F'(x)=f(x)$$

then

$$F(b)-F(a)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \Delta x\sum_{x=0}^{n-1} f(x+n\Delta x)$$

where

$$\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$$

I suggest you look in to the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).